# Poor Graphic Display- Why?

Tags: hardware

Well I 've been using the same hardware along with the same version of blender before, and never had this issue: The surfaces seem jagged/ semi-transparent. (Please see the picture below.)

[image]

The only change is that a new version of windows is installed, and I believe the graphic driver is updated, but somehow the graphic card doesn't seem to be in cooperation with the software. How can I solve this? (I even had 3ds Max tested on this system, and it seemed fine.)

(VGA: Nvidia Gforce GT430, driver version: 388.13/ Blender version: 2.93)

Thank you!

Comment: Hmm... Just curious how I didn't have any problems with the very same model before changing my windows. There was no problem regarding the graphics then. and of course I had the same VGA installed.

Answer (score -1):

Blender's [requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) suggest as a minimum 2 GB of VRAM.  Your graphics card has only half a gigabyte, so you aren't meeting the minimum requirements for running Blender. I don't know if that's your only problem here, but you will experience unwanted behavior using hardware below the minimum recommendations.